# Getting EC2 on-demand instance's usage detail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm currently using AWS Java SDK to do some research and still stuck while retrieving the EC2 instance's daily usage detail with the information about the active time and the cost that have to pay. Could anyone show me the way to get it by providing the instance ID ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried cost explorer API?

Comment: @RaGe I tried, but I need to specify each instance's cost by using their instance-id :( still don't know how to filter